# How can I create a Horizontal Image Gallery

Tags: android, design-patterns

I am trying to create a horizontal like image gallery on one of my activities. I want it to take up about 1/4 of the screen and when you swipe left or right it'll go to the next image. Also over the bottom portion of the image there is an indicator showing you where you are in the list of images. Similar to what was done in these apps:

[image: Grand St App]

[image: FourSquare App]

I can't seem to find out how to create this in android. I'm hoping someone out there has an idea and can point me in the right direction or to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com)?